# securing firebase issue in angular

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i am using angular 11 and created chat component with firebase realtime database. I added following rules to firebase db.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.id === $uid  && auth.provider === 'anonymous'",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.id === $uid  && auth.provider === 'anonymous'"
  }
}
```

chat is working on mobile apps (Android, iOS) but throwing error in Web. firebase Nod/user : permission denied.

please help me to fix the bug.

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szlJX.png)

i was setting rules to firebase Realtime db. not to be accessed publicly.

expectation : chat will work with rules when user is logged in.
Result      : Chat is not working.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

try the following and let me know fi it works

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid  && auth.provider === 'anonymous'",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid  && auth.provider === 'anonymous'"
  }
}
```

you should use `auth.uid` not `auth.id`

Edit :

try the below block

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user_data": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in the above i an assuming (you have not specified yet )your node to be `user_data` that contain `uid`.

if you just want to pass this without 'uid' match or just as rule for all the databse then remove `auth.id === $uid` check because it cann't(hope "why?" should be understood)

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null  && auth.provider === 'anonymous'",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.provider === 'anonymous'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time but it's not working. firebase not accepting these rules.